# allowHtml in setCell google charts table visualization

Tags: google-visualization

Please explain this: `setCell(rowIndex, columnIndex [, value [, formattedValue [, properties]]])`

I want to allowHtml in table cell values. 
My version of setcell is
    `data.setCell(0, 0, facebook.video_title, '<a href=' + "http://www.facebook.com/" + facebook.video_id + '>' + facebook.video_title + '</a>');`

My aim is to open a video link on click of video title. So I am putting an  `a` tag there. And I am calling the draw method like this: `google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable(story_data, {allowHtml:true}));`

By running this sample, I am getting whole `HTML` tag syntax as it is in my visualized table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hard to say without seeing `drawTable`

but I don't think the arguments are being passed properly, try it like this...

```
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function () {
    drawTable(story_data, {allowHtml:true});
});
```

Comment: Yes dude, that's what the problem was! Thanks! Can you explain the functional difference between your syntax and mine ?

Comment: `setOnLoadCallback` expects a reference to a `function` -- with 'your' syntax, you're running the function within the call and returning nothing from `drawTable` to `setOnLoadCallback` -- i'm not the most articulate -- hope this helps